# Unreal engine 5 crash when opening new project

Tags: crash, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

So whenever I create a new project (in my case the thirdperson template) and the shaders start compiling, it crashes after few seconds:
(Updated with the debbuging symbols)

```
Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x0000021ad00205d0

nvwgf2umx
nvwgf2umx
nvwgf2umx
nvwgf2umx
nvwgf2umx
nvwgf2umx
nvwgf2umx
nvwgf2umx
nvwgf2umx
nvwgf2umx
nvwgf2umx
nvwgf2umx
D3D12Core
D3D12Core
dxgi
dxgi
dxgi
dxgi
dxgi
dxgi
dxgi
RTSSHooks64
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI!FD3D12Viewport::PresentChecked() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Viewport.cpp:639]
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI!FD3D12Viewport::Present() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Viewport.cpp:739]
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI!FD3D12CommandContextBase::RHIEndDrawingViewport() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Viewport.cpp:939]
UnrealEditor_RHI!FRHICommand<FRHICommandEndDrawingViewport,FRHICommandEndDrawingViewportString2035>::ExecuteAndDestruct() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\RHI\Public\RHICommandList.h:855]
UnrealEditor_RHI!FRHICommandListBase::Execute() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\RHI\Private\RHICommandList.cpp:438]
UnrealEditor_RHI!<lambda_d9c5c35f8ce97cb91cdbe1d4918d55a5>::operator()() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\RHI\Private\RHICommandList.cpp:744]
UnrealEditor_RHI!TGraphTask<TFunctionGraphTaskImpl<void __cdecl(void),0> >::ExecuteTask() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Async\TaskGraphInterfaces.h:1348]
UnrealEditor_Core!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksNamedThread() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Async\TaskGraph.cpp:760]
UnrealEditor_Core!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksUntilQuit() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Async\TaskGraph.cpp:649]
UnrealEditor_RenderCore!FRHIThread::Run() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\RenderCore\Private\RenderingThread.cpp:332]
UnrealEditor_Core!FRunnableThreadWin::Run() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Windows\WindowsRunnableThread.cpp:149]
```

This happens on both 5.1 and 5.0 versions. I need to fix this since otherwise I can't use the engine.
Thanks a lot for any answers.

Comment: Can you install the debugging symbols with the engine (there is an option for it in the launcher)? This way, we can actually see what crashes.

Comment: @MaxPlay Sure, will do this.

Comment: @MaxPlayUpdated the log with the debugging symbols.

Comment: Looks to me like your solution works well in this case. If it's really a shader compiling or rendering issue, you usually have two options: Revert your graphics driver or change the API. You could also try the latter and use DirectX11 if you have the option. Sometimes it is an issue that comes from epic, sometimes from your machine. That's probably the best advice I can give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It's not ideal and I didn't find the root source of the problem but it works.
So it was caused by the latest nvidia graphics driver https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/198401/en-us/.
I reverted back to this version and works well now:
https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/197461/en-us/